# $X,Y$ euclidean spaces $(dimX=dimY)$; $f:U\subset X \to Y ; f \in \mathbb C^1$ If $f'(a):X \to Y$ is surjection then it is an isomorphism?..

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

$X,Y$ euclidean spaces $(dimX=dimY)$; $f:U\subset X \to Y ; f \in \mathbb C^1$ If $f'(a):X \to Y$ is surjection then the mapping of every ball with a center in $a$ includes a ball centered in $f(a)$.

Now, the answer is given, but there are thing that I do not understand in the beginning, but the second part of the solution is clear. To start:

$a\in U \subseteq X \\ \dim X= \dim Y$
It is said that $f'(a)$ is a linear mapping (does this apply to all functions that are a derivative of a function in $\mathbb C^1$,or in general?)
Then it says that since that $f'(a)$ is surjective that it is an isomorphism. But shouldn't f'(a) be an injective also. If it is that also, why is that? Then the solution goes on to use the theorem of inverse functions, which is clear..

Comment: it is "surjective" I suppose!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative is always a linear map. It is the best linear approximation to a function at a point. In terms of the standard Euclidean bases, it is represented by the Jacobian matrix.

Your second question is just a matter of linear algebra: a linear map between two spaces of the same finite dimension is injective iff it is surjective iff it is an isomorphism. This follows from the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: hey thanks so much!